# checkboxが複数選択された場合と単体の場合で表示されるボタンをかえたい

Tags: jquery

checkboxが複数選択された場合と単体の場合で表示されるボタンを変えたいのですが、
どのようにしたらよいかわからず困っています。

スニペットに記載したもので、
checkboxにチェックをいれると`tab1`のボタンを表示させることができました。
(こちらのスニペットでは、うまくボタンが表示させることができませんでした。。)

ただ、複数選択した場合は`tab2`のボタンを表示させたいのですが、　
どのようにしたらよいかご教授いただけますと大変助かります。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

**参考にしたページ**
[iCheckを利用時のチェックの有る無しで表示を切り替える](https://hacknote.jp/archives/16905/)

下記のように修正してみたことにより、
単体チェック、複数チェックによってボタンの表示内容を変えることはできました。

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  var check_count = $('.check :checked').length;

  if (check_count == 1) {
    $('#tab1').show().addClass('active');
  } else if (check_count > 1 ) {
    $('#tab2').show().addClass('active');
    $('#tab1').hide().removeClass('active');
  }
});

$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
  $('#tab1').hide().removeClass('active');
  $('#tab2').hide().removeClass('active');
});
```

ただ、チェックを外した時にボタンの表示内容をかえるのがうまくできません。
今はチェックを外すと、tab1/tab2のボタンがすべて消えてしまいます。

やりたいことは、
▼複数チェックされていたとき、
すべてのチェックが外された時は、tab1/tab2非表示。
チェックが外されて1個のみチェックされている時は、tab1表示。
チェックが外されても2個以上チェックされている時は、tab２表示。

▼単体チェックされていたとき、
すべてのチェックが外された時は、tab1/tab2が非表示。

```js
/*!
 * iCheck v1.0.1, http://git.io/arlzeA
 * =================================
 * Powerful jQuery and Zepto plugin for checkboxes and radio buttons customization
 *
 * (c) 2013 Damir Sultanov, http://fronteed.com
 * MIT Licensed
 */

(function($) {

  // Cached vars
  var _iCheck = 'iCheck',
    _iCheckHelper = _iCheck + '-helper',
    _checkbox = 'checkbox',
    _radio = 'radio',
    _checked = 'checked',
    _unchecked = 'un' + _checked,
    _disabled = 'disabled',
    _determinate = 'determinate',
    _indeterminate = 'in' + _determinate,
    _update = 'update',
    _type = 'type',
    _click = 'click',
    _touch = 'touchbegin.i touchend.i',
    _add = 'addClass',
    _remove = 'removeClass',
    _callback = 'trigger',
    _label = 'label',
    _cursor = 'cursor',
    _mobile = /ipad|iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|windows phone|opera mini|silk/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

  // Plugin init
  $.fn[_iCheck] = function(options, fire) {

    // Walker
    var handle = 'input[type="' + _checkbox + '"], input[type="' + _radio + '"]',
      stack = $(),
      walker = function(object) {
        object.each(function() {
          var self = $(this);

          if (self.is(handle)) {
            stack = stack.add(self);
          } else {
            stack = stack.add(self.find(handle));
          }
        });
      };

    // Check if we should operate with some method
    if (/^(check|uncheck|toggle|indeterminate|determinate|disable|enable|update|destroy)$/i.test(options)) {

      // Normalize method's name
      options = options.toLowerCase();

      // Find checkboxes and radio buttons
      walker(this);

      return stack.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);

        if (options == 'destroy') {
          tidy(self, 'ifDestroyed');
        } else {
          operate(self, true, options);
        }
          // Fire method's callback
        if ($.isFunction(fire)) {
          fire();
        }
      });

    // Customization
    } else if (typeof options == 'object' || !options) {

      // Check if any options were passed
      var settings = $.extend({
          checkedClass: _checked,
          disabledClass: _disabled,
          indeterminateClass: _indeterminate,
          labelHover: true,
          aria: false
        }, options),

        selector = settings.handle,
        hoverClass = settings.hoverClass || 'hover',
        focusClass = settings.focusClass || 'focus',
        activeClass = settings.activeClass || 'active',
        labelHover = !!settings.labelHover,
        labelHoverClass = settings.labelHoverClass || 'hover',

        // Setup clickable area
        area = ('' + settings.increaseArea).replace('%', '') | 0;

      // Selector limit
      if (selector == _checkbox || selector == _radio) {
        handle = 'input[type="' + selector + '"]';
      }
        // Clickable area limit
      if (area < -50) {
        area = -50;
      }
        // Walk around the selector
      walker(this);

      return stack.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);

        // If already customized
        tidy(self);

        var node = this,
          id = node.id,

          // Layer styles
          offset = -area + '%',
          size = 100 + (area * 2) + '%',
          layer = {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: offset,
            left: offset,
            display: 'block',
            width: size,
            height: size,
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0,
            background: '#fff',
            border: 0,
            opacity: 0
          },

          // Choose how to hide input
          hide = _mobile ? {
            position: 'absolute',
            visibility: 'hidden'
          } : area ? layer : {
            position: 'absolute',
            opacity: 0
          },

          // Get proper class
          className = node[_type] == _checkbox ? settings.checkboxClass || 'i' + _checkbox : settings.radioClass || 'i' + _radio,

          // Find assigned labels
          label = $(_label + '[for="' + id + '"]').add(self.closest(_label)),

          // Check ARIA option
          aria = !!settings.aria,

          // Set ARIA placeholder
          ariaID = _iCheck + '-' + Math.random().toString(36).replace('0.', ''),

          // Parent & helper
          parent = '<div class="' + className + '" ' + (aria ? 'role="' + node[_type] + '" ' : ''),
          helper;

        // Set ARIA "labelledby"
        if (label.length && aria) {
          label.each(function() {
            parent += 'aria-labelledby="';

            if (this.id) {
              parent += this.id;
            } else {
              this.id = ariaID;
              parent += ariaID;
            }

            parent += '"';
          });
        }
          // Wrap input
        parent = self.wrap(parent + '/>')[_callback]('ifCreated').parent().append(settings.insert);

        // Layer addition
        helper = $('<ins class="' + _iCheckHelper + '"/>').css(layer).appendTo(parent);

        // Finalize customization
        self.data(_iCheck, {o: settings, s: self.attr('style')}).css(hide);
        !!settings.inheritClass && parent[_add](node.className || '');
        !!settings.inheritID && id && parent.attr('id', _iCheck + '-' + id);
        parent.css('position') == 'static' && parent.css('position', 'relative');
        operate(self, true, _update);

        // Label events
        if (label.length) {
          label.on(_click + '.i mouseover.i mouseout.i ' + _touch, function(event) {
            var type = event[_type],
              item = $(this);

            // Do nothing if input is disabled
            if (!node[_disabled]) {

              // Click
              if (type == _click) {
                if ($(event.target).is('a')) {
                  return;
                }
                operate(self, false, true);

              // Hover state
              } else if (labelHover) {

                // mouseout|touchend
                if (/ut|nd/.test(type)) {
                  parent[_remove](hoverClass);
                  item[_remove](labelHoverClass);
                } else {
                  parent[_add](hoverClass);
                  item[_add](labelHoverClass);
                }
              }
                if (_mobile) {
                event.stopPropagation();
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        }
          // Input events
        self.on(_click + '.i focus.i blur.i keyup.i keydown.i keypress.i', function(event) {
          var type = event[_type],
            key = event.keyCode;

          // Click
          if (type == _click) {
            return false;

          // Keydown
          } else if (type == 'keydown' && key == 32) {
            if (!(node[_type] == _radio && node[_checked])) {
              if (node[_checked]) {
                off(self, _checked);
              } else {
                on(self, _checked);
              }
            }
              return false;

          // Keyup
          } else if (type == 'keyup' && node[_type] == _radio) {
            !node[_checked] && on(self, _checked);

          // Focus/blur
          } else if (/us|ur/.test(type)) {
            parent[type == 'blur' ? _remove : _add](focusClass);
          }
        });

        // Helper events
        helper.on(_click + ' mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout ' + _touch, function(event) {
          var type = event[_type],

            // mousedown|mouseup
            toggle = /wn|up/.test(type) ? activeClass : hoverClass;

          // Do nothing if input is disabled
          if (!node[_disabled]) {

            // Click
            if (type == _click) {
              operate(self, false, true);

            // Active and hover states
            } else {

              // State is on
              if (/wn|er|in/.test(type)) {

                // mousedown|mouseover|touchbegin
                parent[_add](toggle);

              // State is off
              } else {
                parent[_remove](toggle + ' ' + activeClass);
              }
                // Label hover
              if (label.length && labelHover && toggle == hoverClass) {

                // mouseout|touchend
                label[/ut|nd/.test(type) ? _remove : _add](labelHoverClass);
              }
            }
              if (_mobile) {
              event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      return this;
    }
  };

  // Do something with inputs
  function operate(input, direct, method) {
    var node = input[0],
      state = /er/.test(method) ? _indeterminate : /bl/.test(method) ? _disabled : _checked,
      active = method == _update ? {
        checked: node[_checked],
        disabled: node[_disabled],
        indeterminate: input.attr(_indeterminate) == 'true' || input.attr(_determinate) == 'false'
      } : node[state];

    // Check, disable or indeterminate
    if (/^(ch|di|in)/.test(method) && !active) {
      on(input, state);

    // Uncheck, enable or determinate
    } else if (/^(un|en|de)/.test(method) && active) {
      off(input, state);

    // Update
    } else if (method == _update) {

      // Handle states
      for (var state in active) {
        if (active[state]) {
          on(input, state, true);
        } else {
          off(input, state, true);
        }
      }
    } else if (!direct || method == 'toggle') {

      // Helper or label was clicked
      if (!direct) {
        input[_callback]('ifClicked');
      }
        // Toggle checked state
      if (active) {
        if (node[_type] !== _radio) {
          off(input, state);
        }
      } else {
        on(input, state);
      }
    }
  }
    // Add checked, disabled or indeterminate state
  function on(input, state, keep) {
    var node = input[0],
      parent = input.parent(),
      checked = state == _checked,
      indeterminate = state == _indeterminate,
      disabled = state == _disabled,
      callback = indeterminate ? _determinate : checked ? _unchecked : 'enabled',
      regular = option(input, callback + capitalize(node[_type])),
      specific = option(input, state + capitalize(node[_type]));

    // Prevent unnecessary actions
    if (node[state] !== true) {

      // Toggle assigned radio buttons
      if (!keep && state == _checked && node[_type] == _radio && node.name) {
        var form = input.closest('form'),
          inputs = 'input[name="' + node.name + '"]';

        inputs = form.length ? form.find(inputs) : $(inputs);

        inputs.each(function() {
          if (this !== node && $(this).data(_iCheck)) {
            off($(this), state);
          }
        });
      }
        // Indeterminate state
      if (indeterminate) {

        // Add indeterminate state
        node[state] = true;

        // Remove checked state
        if (node[_checked]) {
          off(input, _checked, 'force');
        }
          // Checked or disabled state
      } else {

        // Add checked or disabled state
        if (!keep) {
          node[state] = true;
        }
          // Remove indeterminate state
        if (checked && node[_indeterminate]) {
          off(input, _indeterminate, false);
        }
      }
        // Trigger callbacks
      callbacks(input, checked, state, keep);
    }
      // Add proper cursor
    if (node[_disabled] && !!option(input, _cursor, true)) {
      parent.find('.' + _iCheckHelper).css(_cursor, 'default');
    }
      // Add state class
    parent[_add](specific || option(input, state) || '');

    // Set ARIA attribute
    disabled ? parent.attr('aria-disabled', 'true') : parent.attr('aria-checked', indeterminate ? 'mixed' : 'true');

    // Remove regular state class
    parent[_remove](regular || option(input, callback) || '');
  }
    // Remove checked, disabled or indeterminate state
  function off(input, state, keep) {
    var node = input[0],
      parent = input.parent(),
      checked = state == _checked,
      indeterminate = state == _indeterminate,
      disabled = state == _disabled,
      callback = indeterminate ? _determinate : checked ? _unchecked : 'enabled',
      regular = option(input, callback + capitalize(node[_type])),
      specific = option(input, state + capitalize(node[_type]));

    // Prevent unnecessary actions
    if (node[state] !== false) {

      // Toggle state
      if (indeterminate || !keep || keep == 'force') {
        node[state] = false;
      }
        // Trigger callbacks
      callbacks(input, checked, callback, keep);
    }
      // Add proper cursor
    if (!node[_disabled] && !!option(input, _cursor, true)) {
      parent.find('.' + _iCheckHelper).css(_cursor, 'pointer');
    }
      // Remove state class
    parent[_remove](specific || option(input, state) || '');

    // Set ARIA attribute
    disabled ? parent.attr('aria-disabled', 'false') : parent.attr('aria-checked', 'false');

    // Add regular state class
    parent[_add](regular || option(input, callback) || '');
  }
    // Remove all traces
  function tidy(input, callback) {
    if (input.data(_iCheck)) {

      // Remove everything except input
      input.parent().html(input.attr('style', input.data(_iCheck).s || ''));

      // Callback
      if (callback) {
        input[_callback](callback);
      }
        // Unbind events
      input.off('.i').unwrap();
      $(_label + '[for="' + input[0].id + '"]').add(input.closest(_label)).off('.i');
    }
  }
    // Get some option
  function option(input, state, regular) {
    if (input.data(_iCheck)) {
      return input.data(_iCheck).o[state + (regular ? '' : 'Class')];
    }
  }
    // Capitalize some string
  function capitalize(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }
    // Executable handlers
  function callbacks(input, checked, callback, keep) {
    if (!keep) {
      if (checked) {
        input[_callback]('ifToggled');
      }
        input[_callback]('ifChanged')[_callback]('if' + capitalize(callback));
    }
  }
})(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);


// checkboの状態によってボタンを表示・非表示
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  var check_count = $('.check :checked').length;

  if (check_count == 1) {
    $('#tab1').show().addClass('active');
  } else if (check_count > 1 ) {
    $('#tab2').show().addClass('active');
    $('#tab1').hide().removeClass('active');
  }
});

$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
  $('#tab1').hide().removeClass('active');
  $('#tab2').hide().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
#tab1 {
  display: none;
}
#tab2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  
 <section class="content container-fluid">
  <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header">
      <div id="tab1">
        <button>B</button>
        <button>C</button>
      </div>
      <div id="tab2">
        <button>D</button>
        <button>E</button>
      </div>   
     </div>
  </div>
   <div class="box-body">
     <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered dataTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>id</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check">
              </td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check">
              </td>
              <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check">
              </td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr> 
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: icheck.jsがないのでボタンの表示が効いてないのではと思います。htmlは開発環境と同様でしょうか？

Comment: 現状のコードでは質問文に書かれているエラーを再現することが出来ませんでした。もし他に記述しているコードがあれば、可能な限り省略せずに質問文に追記していただけませんか？

Comment: icheck.js を追加してみましたが、まだ同じ環境にできないようなので、何が不足しているか再度見直します。

Comment: 上記のコードが動作している前提ですが「$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){」の処理時も「check_count」で判断する処理を記載すればいいと思いますがどうでしょうか？

Comment: `$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){」の処理時も「check_count」で判断する`　をどのように書けば良いかわからず、ご教授いただけますとありがたいですm(_ _)m

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', updateButtons);
$('input').on('ifUnchecked', updateButtons);

function updateButtons(event) {
  var check_count = $('.icheckbox_flat-blue :checked').length;
  if (check_count == 0) {
    $('#tab1').hide().removeClass('active');
    $('#tab2').hide().removeClass('active');
  } else if (check_count == 1) {
    $('#tab1').show().addClass('active');
    $('#tab2').hide().removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('#tab1').hide().removeClass('active');
    $('#tab2').show().addClass('active');
  }
}
```

上記のようにしたら、希望の動作になった。